# How to use for loop variable inside if block

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

```
for instance in GratuityPayment.objects.all():
        print instance.date_paid
        if (employment_number == instance.employment_number):
            raise forms.ValidationError('This Employment Mumber was paid on ' + str(instance.date_paid) + '. You cannot proceed with this retirement')
```

**print instance.date_paid** in printing all the date_paid that are stored in the database  but **str(instance.date_paid)** is given None.

Am having the following line as my output

**This Employment Mumber was paid on None. You cannot proceed with this retirement**

How can i use **instance.date_paid** inside the if statement.

Comment: what is the GratuityPayment class?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to not apply the check when `date_paid` is `None`:

```
for instance in GratuityPayment.objects.all():
    if instance.date_paid is not None and employment_number == instance.employment_number:
        raise forms.ValidationError('This Employment Mumber was paid on ' + str(instance.date_paid) + '. You cannot proceed with this retirement')
```

But, why don't use [`.filter()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) and get only relevant records in the first place:

```
GratuityPayment.objects.filter(date_paid__isnull=False, 
                               employment_number=employment_number)
```

Comment: How do i use the variable in the for loop inside the if block?

Answer (score 0):

It is actually working. Its Given None because that particular Table row did have None in the table.

I just populated the date_paid and it returned the date instead of None.